# Paralloid Eclipse setup

Tags: android, eclipse, parallax

I want to use [Paralloid](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Paralloid) on my eclipse project, but Eclipse doesnt recognize Paralloid as a library.

this is the library i want to use

```
https://github.com/chrisjenx/Paralloid
```

I have tried to google it but couldnt find any help.

After importing Paralloid on Eclipse the properties >> android >> add(under library section) is empty.
i tried to add in build path but still no help...

The sample project is also not working; it crashes before showing anything on screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: were you able to get this to work? i'm having the exact same issue

Comment: got some help from here http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/unsupported_gradle_dsl_method_found_mavendeployer?utm_content=reply_link&utm_medium=email&utm_source=reply_notification#reply_13951458 but not solved yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, So I built the library in Eclipse.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25650355/Library-Paralloid.zip

Usage is the same like the main library.

Enjoy ;)

Comment: thats gr8! but can u see parallex effect? i have followed the step and it is just a normal scrollview no parallex effect...can u share any sample project if u have one?

Comment: have a sample. (you can look at his sample code.) this library didn't work for me because it interfered with the themeing i have on my listview.